# How to perform enhancement operations on an satellite imagery in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, imagery, remote-sensing

I am a new user of QGIS please suggest how to perform image enhancement operations on an satellite imagery like ratioing, contrast stretching, edge engancement, filtering etc. in QGIS?

Answer (score 4):

in qgis for contrast stretching:

- Right click your layer > Properties > Style , at the lower right Contrast Enhancement to Stretch To MinMax

  and in Raster menu you have lots of thing for imagery as Raster to vector,contour, clipper, proximity...

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

SAGA, GRASS and OTB (orfeo toolbox) have some powerful image filtering algorithms including Gaussian filter, Laplacian filter etc.

The processing toolbox in QGIS3 has a search box. You can type a keyword into the processing toolbox to search for any (filtering) algorithm of your choice.